# Is it possible to insert a number into a sorted array, time: log(n)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, time

I have a sorted array of integers (of size n) and would like to insert a new element into the array, is it possible to do so in O(log(n))? I need to keep an insertion and find computational complexity of O(log(n))).

Right now the only idea I have is to do binary search in order to find the desired index for insertion - this would take O(log(n)), but then I would have to create a new array and copy the entire cells which would take O(n).

EDIT:
It was solved by using an [AVL Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) instead, that way any new elements added takes O(log(n)) and finding an element takes O(log(n))

Comment: More details please. We are not magicians who can see what you're working with, as much as we want to be one.

Comment: Yes, you have the best possible algorithm, but moving all the elements will be O(n).  That's the best you'll be able to do.

Comment: If it is an array, I.e. a continues area of memory, and the elements are integers sorted, then by definition insert an element at the beginning of the array requires pushing all the other elements. Saying that, if you just need an "array interface", then other data structures will give you what you need. e.g C++ std::vector has insert of lof(n).

Comment: Can't you use a doubly linked list to store the elements? Then adding and removing won't be hard.

Comment: @kakrafoon yes, that could be a solution as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"is it possible to do so in log(n)? " - in short no.  From my recollections and experience inserting into an arbitrary position in an *array* is always *O(N)*, almost by definition.  If you want faster performance use something like the [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) class.